# Use ruby variable after event trigger

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

I have this script in a `new.html.erb` file, at the bottom, in a script tag:

```
 $('div #mainPhotoDropzone').dropzone({
        url: "/photos?post_id=" + $("#post_form").data('post-id'),
        complete: function(file){
          var url = "<%= @post.photos.first.file.path %>";
          $.get(url, function(data){
            $('#mainPhotoDropzone').attr('style', "background-image: url('" + data.main_photo + "')");
          })
         }
```

However, the `@post.photos.first.file.path` doesn't yet exists on page load so I have an error. Since I'm calling this variable on the `complete` event (and it exists at this particular time), should I place this script in another file and require it in my `new.html.erb` to make this work ? Do I have to place it in a `js.erb` file ?

More generally, how can I use erb after page load in my javascript without it being interpreted ?

Comment: The ruby stuff is evaluated on the server, while the JavaScript runs on the client. If you want to do something involving the server when a client-side event happens, you'll have to issue an HTTP request to the server (ajax).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Pointy  . I'm already doing an AJAX request: the dropzone sends the image to the server via Ajax, and I want to use this image on the complete event of the dropzone. Since the ruby is evaluated on page load, how can I have a file that will contain this piece of erb, and be evaluated when the complete event occurs ?

Comment: Your server-side code needs to send back that URL as part of the response somehow. (The `file` parameter to that "complete" handler.) What does the ajax action return?

Comment: In the Create action of my controller, I did this: 

if photo.save!
      render json: { message: 'success', fileID: photo.id }, status: 200

Comment: It's confusing because it looks like there are **2** operations to the server. What is that `.dropzone()` thing? That has a response coming from somewhere ("file"). Anyway the server-side code has to add the path information to its JSON response, and then the JavaScript code on the client can get it out (much like how you're getting "main_photo" out of the JSON response to that `$.get()` call).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> More generally, how can I use erb after page load in my javascript
>   without it being interpreted ?

You can't do that. Javascript is client-side, ruby is server-side. If you want to handle both at the same time you can consider ActionCable or even the Volt framework. But it's not really suited for your usecase.

As @Pointy pointed out in the comments, you want to get your `url` from the server. Actually you don't even need it, just do the work once for all. Example :

```
 $('div #mainPhotoDropzone').dropzone({
        url: "/photos?post_id=" + $("#post_form").data('post-id'),
        complete: function(data){
            $('#mainPhotoDropzone').attr('style', "background-image: url('" + data.main_photo + "')");
        }
})
```